# python script does not work but individual shell command does

Tags: android, python, shell, adb, android-uiautomator

I am trying to run this piece of python code to learn how to use uiautomator to do android testing.

```
from uiautomator import device as d
d(index = 2, className='android.widget.TextView').click() #menu button
print 'inside menu button'
d(text='People', className='android.widget.TextView').click() #contacts
print 'inside contacts'
#loop to add a contact  
d(resourceId= 'com.android.contacts:id/menu_add_contact', className='android.widget.TextView').click()
```

This piece of code does not work when i run it as a python script `python add_contact.py`

however, when i run it sequentially like this.

```
python #enters the shell 
from uiautomator import device as d
d(index = 2, className='android.widget.TextView').click() #menu button
d(text='People', className='android.widget.TextView').click() #contacts
d(resourceId= 'com.android.contacts:id/menu_add_contact', className='android.widget.TextView').click()
```

Basically what i done is to enter the python shell and enter the commands one by one instead of running it as a script. The outcome is that the contacts book icon is not pressed in the script but entering it manually it would work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Cyphase the command does not get run

Comment: but what any print when it not get run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i have solved this via this code.

```
from uiautomator import device as d
d(index = 2, className='android.widget.TextView').click() #menu button
print 'inside menu button'
d(index='15', className='android.widget.TextView').click() #contacts
print 'inside contacts'
#loop to add a contact  
d(resourceId= 'com.android.contacts:id/menu_add_contact', className='android.widget.TextView').click()
```

It might be a lag issue

by changing

```
d(text='People', className='android.widget.TextView').click() #contacts
```

to this

```
d(index='15', className='android.widget.TextView').click() #contacts
```